Multiple regions with one jobrunr storage
I want to run jobrunr in 2 different regions. Each region will have its own jobrunr instances running. Both regions will read and write to the same database. Will jobrunr work out of the box for this setup?
Thanks
I tried to go through jobrunr's documentation but couldn't find any information about multi-region support. I also went through other similar questions multiple services with one jobrunr storage, however it doesn't answer for me as I am expecting to run jobrunr for the same service but in different regions for resiliency.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It will working. I have similar setup make sure the storage provider points to same DB. @Neha

@Sreemat what DB you're using? Can jobrunr write to multiple nodes of a DB or it always has to write to single node but can read from multiple nodes (read replicas).

MS SQL.. Why jobrunr need to write to multiple node. If it update one of the DB, The DB should replicate to all of it node right?
